# Why does importing my custom modul show the whole script code?

Tags: powershell

**The Problem:**

I have a big custom modul with tons of functions. I import it via my profile.ps1 file like this:

`import-module "\\server\path\Filename.psm1"`

This worked perfectly in the past. 
But since today I added in new code to my `profile.ps1` code.

What I changed was that I create a 2nd session to Office 365.
The whole `ps1` file looks like this now:

```
# Log Files
Start-Transcript

# Session leeren
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

#Session auf onPrem

$onpremSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://onPremServer/powershell
Import-PSSession $onpremSession -Prefix onPremises

#Session auf Cloud

$cloudSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential "$env:USERNAME@mycompany.com" -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $cloudSession -Prefix Cloud


#Modul Import von allen Scripts
import-module "\\server\path\Filename.psm1"

# Show available CMDlets
get-commands
```

**So since today when I start my powershell using this `profile.ps`, powershell loads in, creates the session and then when it jumps to the `import-module` line it shows the whole code from my custom modul.**

Screenshot:

[image]

Why? I already tried to add a `-Verbose:$false` but that doesn't change anything.

**How can I get rid of the whole script block it shows from the custom modul?**

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by saving the `import-PsSession` output into a variable like this: `$s = Import-PSSession $onpremSession -Prefix onPremises`
This gets rid of the output.